# Select date with null value in 2 table

Tags: sql-server

I Have 2 Table in SQL SERVER 2005:

firts table :
  Tanggal
  2015/01/01
  2015/01/02
  2015/01/03
  2015/01/04
  2015/01/05
  2015/01/06

Second Table :
  Tanggal               Jam_Masuk          Jam_Pulang
  2015/01/01        08:00:00                17:00:00          
  2015/01/03        08:00:00                17:00:00     
  2015/01/05        08:00:00                17:00:00    
  2015/01/06        08:00:00                17:00:00

I want select like this :
  Tanggal               Jam_Masuk          Jam_Pulang 
            Total              Status
  2015/01/01        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK         
  2015/01/02        --:--:--                   --:--:--                  --:--:--           ALPHA/IZIN         
  2015/01/03        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK         
  2015/01/04        --:--:--                   --:--:--                  --:--:--           ALPHA/IZIN         
  2015/01/05        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK         
  2015/01/06        08:00:00                17:00:00               09:00:00        OK

Note : Field Total = Jam_Pulang - Jam_Masuk

Thanks Before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query for your required output

```
SELECT t1.Tanggal,
       t2.Jam_Masuk,
       t2.Jam_Pulang,
       Datepart(hh, Cast(t2.Jam_Pulang AS TIME)) - Datepart(hh, Cast(t2.Jam_Masuk AS TIME)) AS Total,
       CASE
         WHEN Jam_Masuk IS NULL
              AND Jam_Pulang IS NULL THEN  'ALPHA/IZIN'
         ELSE 'ok'
       END [status]
FROM   firts_table t1
       LEFT JOIN second_table t2
              ON t1.Tanggal = t2.Tanggal
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Tanggal                  Jam_Masuk  Jam_Pulang  Total   status
2015-01-01 00:00:00.000  08:00:00   17:00:00     9       ok
2015-01-02 00:00:00.000  NULL       NULL        NULL    ALPHA/IZIN
2015-01-03 00:00:00.000  08:00:00   17:00:00     9      ok
2015-01-04 00:00:00.000  NULL       NULL       NULL     ALPHA/IZIN
2015-01-05 00:00:00.000  08:00:00   17:00:00     9      ok
2015-01-06 00:00:00.000  08:00:00   17:00:00     9      ok
```

Comment: It work. Thanks. But if in second table i add [id user] i cannot found all date (with null value) Thanks.